# Match ANY word in string variable to data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match, custom-data-attribute

I have a Dynamic string of selected payment options "visa, mastercard"

I am then saying if a rows data-attribute-payment Contains ANY of the words in that string show the Row

The problem is the regex is taking the whole string and trying to find an exact match within data-attribute.

So instead of the code saying:
This Rows data attribute contains visa so show it

it says:
This rows data attribute shows visa but NOT visa, mastercard - Therefore its not a match

```
 //for all html Rows
 $(".loading tr").hide().filter(function() {
        var rtnData = "";

 //string of payments
        var payOptionsString="visa, mastercard";
  //declare as a regex ignoring case and matching globally
        var     regExApproved    = new RegExp(payOptionsString, 'ig');

         //returns all rows that have an attribute that matches the 
regexTest
        rtnData = (
                $(this).attr("data-payment").match(regExApproved)     
            );
```

So how do I make the match allow a match if the .attr('data-payment') contains ANY word found in the given string?

Comment: To match either `visa` or `mastercard` use `"visa|mastercard"`

Comment: Your regex pattern will match only if the string explicit have "visa, mastercard".

If you want to match if the string CONTAINS any of these words, you can do something like visa|mastercard.

Comment: you can try with `$(this).attr("data-payment").match(/^(visa|mastercard)$/)`

Comment: Hi yes thanks.. The problem is the string is dynamic - Meaning it will change and contain 'visa,mastercard, something else'
So i need it to search the string and match Anything in it

Comment: If you want to match anything, you don't need a regex. You must have some restrictions on what you want to match.

Comment: well the restriction is only that the match term should be contained in $payOptionsString

Comment: Maybe If I had a forloop on the string so that each word in it can be regexd

Comment: No, just use: var payOptionsString="visa|mastercard|anything";

Comment: But that string is dynamically made so can contain different words in the future.

Hope I have explained the problem right

Comment: if payOptionsString has comma separated values, split the string using `,` as delimiter, trim it and then append all the values with `|` as delimiter (or you could directly replace `,` and `, ` with `|`) and use the appended value in new Regexp statement.

Comment: Could you show me an example?
I have made a string like visa | Mastercard | etc but it doesnt match